# R rowSums for multiple groups of variables using mutate and for loops by prefix of variable names

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, prefix

I have multiple variables grouped together by prefixes (par___, fri___, gp___ etc) there are 29 of these groups.

Each variable has a value of 0 or 1. What I need to do is sum these groups (i.e., partner___1 + partner___2 etc) and if the rowSums = 0, make each of the variables NA.

for example. My data looks like this:

| par___ | par___2 | fri___1 | fri___2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

and I want it to look like this:

| par___ | par___2 | fri___1 | fri___2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | 0 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |

I can do it individually like this:

```
  df<- df%>%
    mutate(rowsum = rowSums(.[grep("par___", names(.))])) %>% 
    mutate_at(grep("par___", names(.)), funs(ifelse(rowsum == 0, NA, .))) %>%
    select(-rowsum)
```

And I figured I could do something like this:

```
vars <- c('par___', "fri___','gp___')


for (i in vars) {
  df<- df%>%
    # creates a "rowsum" column storing the sum of columns 1:2 
    mutate(rowsum = rowSums(.[grep(i, names(.))])) %>% 
    # applies, to columns 1:2, a function that puts NA when the sum of the rows is 0
    mutate_at(grep(i, names(.)), funs(ifelse(rowsum == 0, NA, .))) %>%
    select(-rowsum) 
    }
```

There are no error messages but it doesn't work.

Also, I've tried mutate(across()) instead of mutate_at() and get this error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Can't convert a list to function
i Input `..1` is `across(grep(i, names(.)), list(ifelse(rowsum == 0, NA, .)))`.

And, I've tried list instead of funs and get this error:

Error in rowsum == 0 :
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidyverse option will be:

```
df %>%
  stack() %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  group_by(grp = row_number(), grp2 = str_remove(ind, "_.*")) %>%
  mutate(values = values + na_if(all(values==0), 1)) %>%
  pivot_wider(grp, ind, values_from = values)
  
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   grp [4]
    grp par___1 par___2 fri___1 fri___2
  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1      NA      NA       1       1
2     2       0       1      NA      NA
3     3      NA      NA       1       0
4     4      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

If on the other hand, you will prefer base R, then you could do:

```
d <- ave(unlist(df), row(df), sub("_.*", "", names(df))[col(df)], FUN = function(x) x * NA ^ all(x==0))
array(d, dim(df), dimnames(df))

  par___1 par___2 fri___1 fri___2
1      NA      NA       1       1
2       0       1      NA      NA
3      NA      NA       1       0
4      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Take note that the last one is a matrix and you can turn it to a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks so much. They both work! Thanks so much. They even work with missing data (which I don't have yet, but may by the end of data collecting). Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `split.default` :

```
do.call(cbind, unname(lapply(split.default(df, 
     sub('(\\w+)_.*', '\\1', names(df))), function(x) {
           x[rowSums(x) == 0, ] <- NA
           x
})))

#  fri___1 fri___2 par___ par___2
#1       1       1     NA      NA
#2      NA      NA      0       1
#3       1       0     NA      NA
#4      NA      NA     NA      NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works, but I tried it with an NA and got an error. Really appreciate your help though. I don't have missing data yet but we haven't finished data collection and we may get some NAs in there. The above solution worked too. Thanks so much!!

Comment: If you can have `NA`s in data you can use `x[rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ] <- NA`

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this code. It is exactly what I want! I've been using the tidyverse code above but for some reason, once I updated R and Rstudio it no longer works. I'm now using the base code you provided and it works beautifully. But wondering if anyone else has had the same problem.